# Call non-static function from static function

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I am not able to call a non-static function from a static function (or) i want to call a javascript function from static function.

```
[WebMethod]
public static void add_items(string itemslist)
{
    get_price(itemslist); // Error An object reference is required for non-static

    //(or)
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, 
        this.GetType(), 
        "script", 
        "<Script language='javascript' "
           + "type='text/javascript'>message();</script>", 
        false); //Error in this, this
}

protected void get_price(string item_id)
{

}
```

Comment: If you want to call an instance method, you need an instance. How about creating one?

Comment: Is this real code? You cannot use 'this' in a static method.

Answer (score 3):

Since static methods are accessible regardless whether or not you instantiated that class, accessing a class member from a static method could potentially mean that you're referencing something that doesn't yet exist in the stack or the heap, thus creating an exception at runtime.

For this reason, you can't reference non-static members inside static methods without instantiating the non-static member first, and that's why you're getting an error. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can't. If you want to do this, you need to instantiate the object containing the non-static method first.

Answer (score 1):

The straight option is create object of class, and than call method. if you are not updating the object state (seems to me in this case), than convert the `get_price` method signature to `static`

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you can't call instance method inside a static method. Is following possible in your situation?

```
    [WebMethod]
    public static void add_items(string itemslist, Action<string> instanceMethod)
    {
        //get_price(itemslist);// Error An object reference is required for non-static

        instanceMethod(itemlist);
    }

    protected void get_price(string item_id)
    {

    }
```

Then pass get_price as argument like so.

```
add_items(anItemslist, get_price);
```