# Call a javascript function from c# static method

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using the below client script in aspx code behind to call a javascript function. But the below client script in public static method so i got the error in registerstartupscript first argument.My older post is here [Call non-static function from static function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14978332/call-non-static-function-from-static-function)

If any one have a possible solutions please post..

Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page), "SymbolError", "from_bill_tab();");

Comment: Are you trying to register a startup javascript in a [WebMethod] ?

Comment: No can u tell me that..

Comment: I'm just looking at the other post you linked to, and it looks like your trying to do it in a [WebMethod]

Comment: yes [WebMethod] only allow the public static method. Am i right?. Thats why i need this type of client script to call a js function

Comment: I don't think you can do this (register a script) from a static WebMethod in an aspx page. Is your intent to call your WebMethod from the aspx page via javascript/ajax?

Comment: NO i want to call a javascript function from code behind static method.

Comment: Why is it a WebMethod?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page), "SymbolError", 
 "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Error !!!');</script>");
```

Comment: Got error the name ClientScript doesn't exist in the current context.

Comment: Try to use Page.ClientScript

Comment: It also given the error An object reference is required for the non-static method,or property

Comment: try to google first related to that error and you got the answer for the question. Try to post a new question which is related to that

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I spent more time to solve this issue. But i can't.

Answer (score -2):

I know this is an old question.I am answering this to help new users who come across this question.

To use clientscript inside a static method pass the Page object as a parameter to your static method

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           LoadJavascript(Page);
        }



public static void LoadJavascript( Page page)
        {

           page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(page.GetType(), "alert", "<script>alert('Hai');</script>");
        }
```

Comment: because the question is that we want to call the javascript through the static method not the load time. First read question carefully then after give the answer according to the question